# Azure DevOps + Lerna how to configure compare url

Tags: azure-devops, lerna

I'm using lerna for monorepo in Azure DevOps

I'm trying to configure the compare url to be

```
{{host}}/{{owner}}/{{repository}}/branchCompare?_a=commits&baseVersion=GT{{previousTag}}&targetVersion=GT{{currentTag}}
```

I have defined a `changelog-preset.config.js`

```
module.exports = Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => require('conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits'))
  .then(presetPromise => presetPromise())
  .then(preset => {
    preset.writerOpts.compareUrlFormat =
      '{{host}}/{{owner}}/{{repository}}/branchCompare?_a=commits&baseVersion=GT{{previousTag}}&targetVersion=GT{{currentTag}}'
    return preset
  })
```

And put it in the `lerna.json`

```
{
  "packages": ["packages/*"],
  "private": true,
  "version": "independent",
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "changelogPreset": "./changelog-preset.config.js",
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "registry": "purposely__removed__",
      "conventionalCommits": true
    },
    "version": {
      "message": "chore(ci): release",
      "changelogPreset": "./changelog-preset.config.js"
    }
  }
}
```

But it ignored the setting.  I would like to understand what is the right way to set the compare url.

Appreciated for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your package.json.

```json
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://your-repo-url",
    "directory": "sub-package-path"
  },
```